# What is the elevation of this mesa in Noctis Labyrinthus?

Tags: mars, geology

I'm interested in the elevation of this mesa in Noctis Labyrinthus. It's located at -6.3, 265.

This image is from
https://www.geo.fu-berlin.de/en/geol/fachrichtungen/planet/press/archiv2016/noctis_labyrinthus1/index.html

In the article, they say that some mesas in Noctis Labyrinthus are up to 6 kilometers high, and the one in the image is "several kilometers" high. I'm interested in a more exact figure, if possible.

[image: Mesa on Noctis Labyrinthus]

Comment: Look up here: http://jmars.mars.asu.edu/maps/?layer=MOLA_Color
colour scale: https://astropedia.astrogeology.usgs.gov/download/Mars/GlobalSurveyor/MOLA/ancillary/colorhillshade_mola_lut.gif